# Simple message authentication code

Tags: mac

I used to figure that message authentication codes function like digital signatures: a hash of a message is calculated and then encrypted with a secret key. To verify the authenticity of a message, the recipient calculates the hash of the message, decrypts the MAC with the secret key, and compares the two. I have not seen a single MAC that works like this. Is this insecure?

Comment: That construction requires collision-resistance of the hash function. $\;$

Comment: @Ricky Demer Yeah, and so does every other friggin' message authentication code, digital signature scheme, and CSPRNG out there. What's your point? That it needs to be a secure hash function is not lost on me.

Comment: My point is that I believe the result "so does every other friggin' message authentication code, digital signature scheme, and CSPRNG out there" would potentially be publishable, since those can be based on one-way functions, and from what I can find [(section 4.3)](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rafael/papers/nonBB.pdf#page=15), there is currently no publicly known way to base collision-resistance on one-way functions. $\:$ (... continued) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (continued ...) $\:$ Also, [what I believe is currently the best known security argument for HMAC](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) only uses pseudorandomness of the compression function. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer is correct. HMAC does not rely on collision resistance of the underlying hash; HMAC-MD5 is still completely sound (although poor taste), outside of its digest length.

Comment: @RickyDemer What "result" would be publishable? I can't really tell from your sentence. If the problem with my simple construction is collision resistance, then digital signatures in public key cryptosystems also suffer from the same problem, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @StephenTouset Then how can any MAC be secure? How is any hash secure?

Comment: The result that "every other friggin' message authentication code, digital signature scheme, and CSPRNG out there" "requires collision-resistance of the hash function." $\:$ Collision resistance is the problem, and I'm not aware of any practical implementations that would not necessary immediately fail when a hash collision is found, athough [one can presumably avoid requiring collision resistance](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/HALEVI_UpdateonRandomizedHashing0824.pdf). $\:$

Comment: I'm not certain how either of your questions pertain to my reply. HMAC has a [proof of security](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) that only relies on on the underlying compression function being a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family). It does not rely on any other properties typically expected of a hash function, so *any* PRF can be used. How this would relate to the security properties of any other MAC or to hash functions in general is lost on me.

Comment: Okay, let's formalize a generalized version of my scheme: $M$ is a message (of some length), $K$ is a secret key, (of some length) $H(x)$ is a hash function (of some length), $E_k(x)$ is an encryption function that uses $k$ as its key, and $D_k(x)$ is the corresponding decryption function to $E_k(x)$. The MAC, $MAC$, for $M$ when given $K$ and $E_k(x)$ is equal to $E_K(H(M))$. Verification is performed by comparing $H(m)$ with $D_K(MAC)$.

Comment: @StephenTouset What I meant to ask is why aren't typical RSA signatures that consist of signing a message's hash insecure? My construction seems like a symmetric key equivalent.

Comment: RickyDemer's original response, for starters. At a minimum, your construct would require additional properties from the hash function that are unnecessary in HMAC. Additionally, it requires the use of a block cipher which is unnecessary in HMAC. And that block cipher itself has to have certain security properties, which again is unnecessary in HMAC. Even if your construct is secure, it's slower, more complicated, and is less safe in the event that its underlying building blocks become weakened.

Comment: @StephenTouset : $\:$ Melab didn't say that $E_k$ and $D_k$ would be with a block cipher. $\hspace{1.44 in}$

Comment: Melab: $\;\;\;$ If "typical RSA signatures ... message's hash" aren't insecure, then that's because their hash functions are collision resistant. $\:$ For MACs, I am not aware of any reason to require collision resistance. $\;\;$

Comment: @Melab Your formalized scheme should be part of the question, not a comment. Could you edit it in?

Comment: Your understanding of digital signatures is *also* wrong -- RSA signatures resemble that process, but many other signature schemes have nothing whatsoever to do with encryption schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are Carter-Wegman MACs that work like this; of course, there the "hash" function is not a cryptographical hash function, but instead it is an almost-universal hash (with a key).

If we replace this almost-universal hash, well, we run into some potential problems.

The first one is the malleability of some encryption methods.  If we were to use, say, counter mode, then it would be easy to modify the message arbitrarily.  All one would need to do is compute the hashes of both the original message, and the modified one, and xor in both to the encrypted MAC; this modified MAC would decrypt to the hash of the modified message.  Carter-Wegman MACs don't run into this problem, because we assume that an attacker cannot compute the almost-universal hash function (because they don't have the key).

One way to attempt to get around this problem is simply use ECB mode, and encrypt only one block -- that is certainly not malleable.  This runs into the second potential problem -- hash collisions.  If we use only 128 bits of the hash, someone can find two plaintexts that share those 128 bits, obtain the MAC for one, and then he has found a valid MAC for the other message.  While clearly this isn't as severe as the first problem (where the attacker can generate a valid MAC for any message), it's still enough for us to be wary of this.  Again, Carter-Wegman MACs don't run into this problem.

So, it can potentially work; however we need to choose our encryption method carefully.

Comment: What is the difference between a "universal" hash and a "cryptographical" hash?

Comment: @Melab : $\:$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Not seeing where the "universal" comes in.

Comment: Doesn't GMAC fall in this category?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: yes, it is a Carter-Wegman MAC that works like this.